# Intuitive meaning of the probability density function at a point

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, continuity

I understand how to integrate probability density functions to find probability within a certain range.

However, what I don't understand is what it would mean to set the variable (say $x$ or $y$) to a certain value and evaluate the pdf as you would evaluate any other function.

I know this happens when dealing with *conditional density functions* in a multivariable situation. But I'm a little confused as to what this actually signifies.

Comment: you're asking about the "physical" or "practical" explanation of the meaning of the value of the pdf at a specific point?

Comment: This has been asked before. See: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210630/what-does-the-value-of-a-probability-density-function-pdf-at-some-x-indicate

Comment: Probability density is to probability as physical density is to physical mass.

Comment: @whacka can you elaborate on that analogy?

Answer (score 12):

Strictly speaking, at any given point the pdf doesn't mean anything. You can change the value of the pdf at that particular point to be whatever you want, and the distribution of the random variable is the same.

Still, "generically", $f(x)$ is essentially the probability to find the random variable in the interval $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$, divided by $2 \epsilon$. More precisely, if $X$ is a continuously distributed random variable with PDF $f$ and CDF $F$, then

$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \frac{F(x+\epsilon)-F(x-\epsilon)}{2\epsilon} = f(x)$$

at almost every point $x$, in the sense of Lebesgue measure. This is one case of the Lebesgue differentiation theorem. The "exceptional points" where this doesn't happen must all be points of discontinuity of $f$. Two examples:

- the normal distribution with its usual density has no exceptional points
- the exponential distribution with its usual density has $0$ as an exceptional point and no others.

Comment: This equation took me a minute to wrap my head around, but understanding it did good for my intuition muscles.

Answer (score 7):

The *velocity* of a moving particle is the *rate of change* of the *displacement* at that time.

The *probability density* of a continuous real valued random variable is the *rate of change* of the *cumulative probability* at that *point*.

Answer (score 7):

Here's an example that may convey some intuition.

Suppose we consider how much it rains in a given year in Los Angeles.  This random variable, which we shall call $R$, has a distribution, which is a PDF that we may denote $f_R(r)$.

Suppose, for the sake of argument, that $f_R(15) = 0.1$.  Now what does that mean?  Obviously, it doesn't mean that there's a $0.1$ probability that it will rain *exactly* $15$ inches.  That probability is zero, since the rainfall will differ from exactly $15$ inches* almost surely.

Instead, what it means is that the probability of it raining *about* $15$ inches is $0.1$ "per inch."  That is, if we ask how likely it is for the rainfall to be in a given range around $15$ inches, the answer will be approximately $0.1$ times the width of the interval in inches.  Obviously, the answer won't be *exactly* $0.1$ times the width of the interval, in general, but for intervals that are "small enough," the answer will be "close enough" (in a delta-epsilon kind of way for continuous PDFs).

*Ignoring the atomic nature of rain for the moment.