# Probability for membership in different normal distributions

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

i have following problem which I am working on:

Say I want to measure something to find out whether it is more likely to belong to class A or class B.

for class A: p = 1

for class B: p = 5

I measure p = 2.9

The measurement is noisy and normally distributed around p with a certain standard deviation.

I want to know the probability that the "something" I measured belongs to class A.

Now I thought about it the following way. I have 2 normal distributions, with $\mu =1$ and $\mu=5$ and the same sigma.
Based on my findings in [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210630/what-does-the-value-of-a-probability-density-function-pdf-at-some-x-indicate) I would calculate the value $z_1=f_1(2.9)$ and $z_2=f_2(2.9)$ where $f_i$ is the probability density function of the first/second normal distribution.

I then get 2 values, let's say $z_1=5$ and $z_2=15$ . This alone shows me that the thing I measured is more likely to belong to class A. But how can I get a specific probability for the membership to class A ?

I do not know at all whether my approach with the PDF is correct, but please point me in another way if it is totally wrong.

Comment: I know that the values are just for the sake of the example, but note that, if the standard deviation is the same, class A should be more likely than class B, since the distance from the mean is smaller.

Comment: Thanks, you're totally right, I edited my post.

In my head I thought of 0 and 5 instead of 1 and 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a priori probabilities. Then you can apply the Bayes' Theorem.

For instance, if the a priori probability of belonging to class A is 0.9, the a posteriori probability would be
$$\frac{0.9 \cdot 5}{0.9 \cdot 5 + 0.1 \cdot 15} = 0.75.$$

Comment: That would certainly make things easier, but the problem is that this is an old exam assignment and on the sheet it says:

"Furthermore, you have no prior knowledge about whether it is
class A or B (but you know it is either A or B)"

Can I infer that the a priori probabilities for A and B are both 0.5 or not?

And further, does your answer imply that me using the PDF as shown in the original post is a correct way to do this?

Comment: In the real world, finding a priori probabilities is frequently a problem with no obvious answers, especially when we have "no prior knowledge". However, if this is an exam question asking for an objective answer, I would guess that you are expected to start with a 50-50 distribution. And, yes, the use of the pdf to compute a "differential likelihood" is correct.