# Taking PDF values for Likelihood

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, maximum-likelihood

Given that PDF value $f_X(x)$ for a particular $x = x_1$ does not have any probabilistic meaning (by definition $p(x = x_1) = 0$). We still see the use of $f_X(x_1)$ as its likelihood.

My questions are:

1. What is the intuition behind using $f_X(x)$ as the likelihood ?
2. Am I correct if I say that $f_X(x_1)$ holds significance only for comparison purposes with $f_X(x_i), i \ne 1$ and not otherwise?

Comment: The basic rationale is that at the maximum PDF-value (say at $x_1$), the probability of being "very close to" $x_1$ is maximized (assuming the PDF is continuous). So it does have probabilistic meaning, namely $f(x) = \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+} P(|X-x| < \varepsilon) / 2\varepsilon$.

Comment: Milten's comment is good, more info here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/210630/177399

Answer (score 1):

The maximization in maximum-likelihood estimators is w.r.t the unknown parameters over their parametric space, i.e., you maximize $L(\theta; x_1,...,x_n) = \prod_{i=1}^n f(\theta; x_i)$ over $\Theta$. Which, indeed, does not have probabilistic meaning (in the frequentists' point of view).